# MDX: How to exclude ancestors from being returned in this query?

Tags: sql-server, service, mdx, analysis

I have this MDX query:

```
Exists([Group].[Group Hierarchy].allmembers,
    {[Group].[Group Full Name].&[121 - Group A], [Group].[Group Full Name].&[700000 - Group C]})
```

... which works fine EXCEPT that it returns all of the ancestors of the specified groups as well.  What I want is to return JUST the groups from the hierarchy with the specified Group Names (this is a type 2 dimension so there may be many at different levels).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter([Group].[Group Hierarchy].members, instr(@GroupGroupFullName,[Group].[Group Hierarchy].Properties( "Group Full Name" )))

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
[Group].[Group Hierarchy].allmembers
```

with

```
[Group].[Group Hierarchy].[Group Hierarchy]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the issue is with the reference to [Group].[Group Hierarchy].allmembers. I'm guessing that [Group Hierarchy] is some sort of navigational hierarchy with multiple levels. It sounds like what you need to do is to replace [Group Hierarchy] with the name of the attribute that contains your type 2 group members in order to get a list of all the members that exist with the specified "Group Full Name" members.

I would leave Filter(..., Instr()) approach as a last resort as it would be much slower than the equivalent set based operation.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Darren.  [Group Hierarchy] is a parent-child hierarchy of a SCD Type 2 dimension ... which means that over time I have have the same Group at different levels in the hierarchy.  As such, the only way I can think to identify a given Group in such an arrangement consistently is by its name (which isn't subject to a type 2 change and is unique to a given Group).  I have to use the hierarchy in my query in order for all the counts and what not to add up correctly.

Comment: A Parent-Child hierarchy does complicate things somewhat as EXISTS will bring in all the ancestor members. Using Filter() may actually be the simplest solution in this case.